# How to access the instance variable initialized with some value inside a method of superclass in subclass Java

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

**Base Class**

```
public class Base 
{
    public X obj;
    public void setValue()
    {
        obj = new A();
    }

}
```

**Util class**

```
public class Util extends Base
{
    public X obj;

    public Util(X obj)
    {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public void function1()
    {
        obj.m1();  //obj is null
    }

    public void function2()
    {
        obj.m2();  //obj is null
    }

}
```

**Test Class**

```
class Test extends Base
{
    // obj inherited from superclass is null.
    Util utilObj = new Util(obj)

    public void testMethod()
    {
         utilObj.function1();
         utilObj.function2();

    }

}
```

How can i pass the  initialized value in constructor of  util class while creating its object inside Test class so that i can use the method of `util class` .It is giving Null pointer exception. I dont want to expose the call of `setValue()` method inside each `Test class` and **can not declare it as static. i.e  `public static X obj;`in `Base class`** .

Is there any way to access the initialized value of non-static variable initialized inside **any method of superclass** directly inside its subclass like static variable. Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: Use a constructor taking X as parameter in Base

Comment: Your `Util` class has a variable called `obj`, which is different from the `obj` variable in `Base`.  Is that intentional?  Or do you want `Util` to just use the `obj` variable in the `Base` class?

Comment: @Wyzard i just want to use obj variable of Base class in util class.Since i need to pass the obj from Test class so i have declared constructor in Util class,

Answer (score 0):

Try use super();
You should be able to find more info at
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Comment: i have not defined any constructor in Base class so why i need to call super(). How it will help?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `public X obj;` line from the `Util` class.  That line creates a *different* variable in `Util` that "hides" the one from `Base` because it has the same name.  If you remove the `obj` variable from `Util`, writing `obj` in `Util` methods will get you the `Base` variable.

Instead of having the `Util` constructor initialize `obj` directly, it'd be a good idea to give `Base` a constructor:

```
public Base(X obj)
{
    this.obj = obj;
}
```

and then change the `Util` constructor to call it:

```
public Util(X obj)
{
    super(obj);  // Calls Base constructor
}
```

Comment: I can not initialize the obj inside constructor. The value of obj will not be passed from any external class so i do not need constructor in Base class.It has to be initialized in setValue() method of Base class. Thanks for the reply..Please help..